# prevent cross domain requests to my wcf services

Tags: c#, wcf, security, cross-domain

I use wcf ui services communicate between my javacsript (jquery) and server side code. I find this work effectively.

However I want to make it more secure. I can I set up wcf so that the requests to the services can only be made from within the same domain, to prevent external clients from making such requests to my services.

So for example, my service opertion url is http://www.website.com/Service.svc/GetProducts. I want to set up wcf so that only requests from pages in the http://www.website.com are allowed. I presume this is in the realm of cross domain wcf requests but need some assistance in setting this up. Help would be great.

Answer (score 5):

This simply isn't possible if your services are exposed to the web.

If something about your services isn't secure enough for that, you should look into fixing that problem - not trying to prevent people from making requests.

Anyone can always use a debugging proxy like Fiddler, Charles, etc. or a tool like WireShark to send *any data they want* to your services - including a complete replay of a request made via the browser. (Including referrer http headers, etc).

*If your situation allows for it*, perhaps you might consider using a VPN appliance or something similar, and restrict access to users inside your network (or coming in through the VPN). That way there is *less* concern about your security of the services.... **however** it's a known fact that "internal attackers" are just as prevalent, if not more so, than external ones... so don't get too comfy.

Let me head this argument off at the pass too, while I'm at it; someone might suggest that browsers already prevent cross site scripting like that. Yes, that's true. But usually it would be the developer of the other application adding the client side script to call those services - and he/she could just as easily make that request on the server side and proxy the results along to the client.